# Functional programming alternative to buffering recursive foreach loop output

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, functional-programming

I want to turn an associative array `$a = array("key0" => array("key1" => "val0", "key2" => "val1"), "key3" => "val2")` into a string `$s = "key0.key1=val0&key0.key2=val1&key3=val2&` so what I'm currently doing is..

```
function assoc_to_str($var, $acc = array()){
  if(is_array($var)){
    foreach($var as $key => $val){
        assoc_to_str($val, array_merge($acc, array($key)));
    }
  }else{echo join('.',$acc).'='.$var.'&';}
}


function assoc_to_str_buffer($arr){
  ob_start();
  arr_to_str($arr);
  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

..and call `assoc_to_str_buffer()`. Now, this feels quite awkward and I'm guessing it's also not very efficient? Is there a better way in a functional style?

It would also be okay if the output wasn't a consecutive string but an array of the current returns of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution through [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

```
function tree_to_str(array $array, $prefix = '') 
{
    return join('&', array_map(function ($key, $value) use ($prefix) 
    {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            return tree_to_str($value, $prefix.$key.'.');
        } else {
            return $prefix.$key.'='.$value;
        }
    }, array_keys($array), $array));
}
```

More "imperative" solution:

```
function tree_to_str(array $array, $prefix = '') 
{
    $buffer = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $buffer[] = tree_to_str($value, $prefix.$key.'.');
        } else {
            $buffer[] = $prefix.$key.'='.$value;
        }
    }
    return join('&', $buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although, it can be done "functional style". I would suggest not reinvent the recursive wheel and use [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) and [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($a),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

$path = [];
$result = [];
foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    $depth = $iterator->getDepth();
    $path[$depth] = $key;

    if (!$iterator->hasChildren()) {
        $result[] = implode('.', array_slice($path, 0, $depth + 1)) . "=$value";
    }
}
$result = implode('&', $result);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/17f11a8a654c6113904732acd3ec8ea6afba5bc2).

As you can see with iterators you can do this with one simple `foreach`.

Also, it is a bad practice to do `echo` inside the function that does logic.